# Format two divs and two images in one line

Tags: html, css

I have two `ul` lists that I wrapped in `div`s and I want them to be side by side. There's a small icon I have left of each title that I want to float next to the title. Below is the code I have so far. It looks find when the window is large but when the window is smaller the second list is pushed under the icon before both the icon and list are pushed under the first. I don't think I formatted my `css` very well since ideally I would like both the second list and icon to be pushed under the first together, the moment the screen is not wide enough. How should I go about doing this?

Here's my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hw30en5z/2/

```css
#bullet-title {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  color: #004080;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.table-icons {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#split-half {
  padding-top: 2%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
}
#provide {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}
#drawings {
  float: left;
}
.list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.list li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -.7em;
}
.list li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #00AEEF;
}
```

```html
<div id="split-half">
  <img class="table-icons" src="http://animations.fg-a.com/freeicons/1-check-icon-round-purple.png" style="float:left">
  <div id="provide">
    <p id="bullet-title">Title 1:</p>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>adss</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <img class="table-icons" src="http://animations.fg-a.com/freeicons/1-check-icon-round-purple.png" style="float:left">
  <div id="drawings">
    <p id="bullet-title">Title 2:</p>
    <ul class="list">
      <li>dasd</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

Comment: wrap the div and title in an image. set display to inline-block; and give a width to the wrapper divs

Answer (score 0):

You could use responsive css to format the site when the screen has different widths. For this, you use the `@media` tags.

With this, you could make it so that once the screen was a certain width, both of the titles/lists go under the image.

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    //css to style objects when screen is smaller than 500px
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    //css to style objects when screen is bigger than 500px
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block` on two wrapper divs, to display 2 columns (see example below).

Some notes:

- don't use inline styles like `<img style="float:left">` if you can avoid it. Your code will soon be a mess, if you mix inline styles with those of your CSS file
- don't use IDs multiple times, like `<p id="bullet-title">`. Use classes instead.

```css
.section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
.section > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.bullet-title {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  color: #004080;
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.table-icons {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#split-half {
  padding-top: 2%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
}
.list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.list li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -.7em;
}
.list li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #00AEEF;
}
```

```html
<div id="split-half">
  <div class="section">
    <img class="table-icons" src="http://animations.fg-a.com/freeicons/1-check-icon-round-purple.png">
    <div id="provide">
      <p class="bullet-title">Title 1:</p>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>adss</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <img class="table-icons" src="http://animations.fg-a.com/freeicons/1-check-icon-round-purple.png">
    <div id="drawings">
      <p class="bullet-title">Title 2:</p>
      <ul class="list">
        <li>dasd</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for this the bullets line up with the image. I'd like it to look the way it does in my example with the list lining up with the title and the images to the left.

Comment: updated my answer - removed the float totally. Now if the viewport is to small, the second div should move completely below the first one.